# How can I reply an email in the same the thread? with sendgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using .net with sendgrid and I want to send an email like a reply but Sendgrid sends my email like a new thread. After some researching I send my header like this:

```
"In-Reply-To":"<message-id>"
"Message-ID":"<message-id>"
"References":"<message-id>"
```

I am not sure if my headers are correct but I think the problem is in the body because I think I should not send a subject but if I don't send it, Sendgrid shows an error and if I send it, it doesn't send the email like a reply.
Here is my body:

```
{
    "personalizations": [
        {
            "to": [
                {
                    "email": "jhonDoe@email.com",
                    "name": "John Doe"
                }
            ],
            "subject": "Hello, World!"
        }
    ],
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text/plain",
            "value": "Heya!"
        }
    ],
    "from": {
        "email": "sam.smith@example.com",
        "name": "Sam Smith"
    },
    "reply_to": {
        "email": "sam.smith@example.com",
        "name": "Sam Smith"
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you set the headers? Looking at their API there should be a "headers" key in your json and you don't have such.

Comment: Message-ID is unique id of your message, you should not set to to id of the message you are replying to

Answer (score 0):

Threads are usually something each email client can handle differently to visualize the items in your inbox. So it's not a standard you can rely on. In Gmail and other large providers, it works if you use the same subject as the original email with a "RE: " prefix.

Here's an example:
The subject of the original email: "Hello World"
The subject line of your response: "RE: Hello World"